# Validar email y numero de telefono en swift

Tags: swift

Como puedo validar en 2 `textfield` si los datos que están introduciendo son:
Un email y un numero de teléfono??

Tengo este código:

```
campoMovil.keyboardType = .numberPad
campoEmail.keyboardType = .emailAddress
```

Comment: Una idea seria usar [tag:regex]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando termines de recoger los valores les pasas este filtro:

```
class func isOnlyNumbers(string: String) -> Bool {
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "\\d{10}").evaluateWithObject(string)
}

class func isValidEmail(string: String) -> Bool {
    let emailReg = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailReg)
    return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(string)
}
```

Comment: que foto de perfil mas adecuada hahah